# how can i change the string format specifier color in intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Please, I just came from using visual studio code with golang and there it did show me the format specifier (format specifiers examples: %s, %d, %c, etc.) of the same color as that of a variable (in my case, I want it to look the same color as that of a variable). Sorry for my english, I translated it with google translate

All the string have the same color including the format specifier. I just want to change the color of the format specifier.

Comment: I only see an option for complete string values, but maybe there's a tweak somewhere.